# Android App Keeps crashing because of iText

Tags: android, itext

I am having problems with my android app, when ever I try to run the app it crashes immediately. I believe it is because of iText and yes I am using the iText for Andorid. I am wondering if there is anyway to fix the issue.

> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.itextpdf.text.Document
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at struct.txi.taxilog.PdfMaker.(PdfMaker.java:26)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at struct.txi.taxilog.LogInformation.onCreate(LogInformation.java:74)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>
> 08-02 01:03:06.430: E/AndroidRuntime(2300):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Seems like you didn't bundle iText with your APK: your application can't find the `Document` class. What's the size of your APK? That could be an easy check to see if iText is shipped with your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot about bundling. Fixed the problem :)